# Как правильно упаковать проект на гитхаб?

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, github

я сделал простенькое asp.net mvc приложение используя EF Database First далее залил на гитхаб, он при скачке на другой машине он не работает, как правильно залить/ упаковать проект на гитхаб что бы на другой машине все работало?
Вот ссылка на проект https://github.com/Kioshilol/Test-task

Ошибки при нажатии на ссылки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создаете репозиторий пустой. Клонируете его на свой компьютер => у вас появляется папка (со скрытой папкой `.git`). В этой папке создаете новый солюжн и пушите.

Comment: а что делать с бд?

Comment: Я вам уже объяснял: большинство тех, кто может ответить, реагируют на те метки, на которые подписаны. Вы упорно ставите малорелевантную метку. Просто пройдитесь по меткам, посмотрите, сколько человек подписаны на ту или иную. Сделайте выводы. / И да, главную страницу сайта просматривают далеко не все.

Comment: БД - enity (code first) и писать инициализацию. Либо по старинке дампом.

Comment: У вас в проекте пара проблем. Имя бандла на странице указано `bundles/bootstrap`, а в коде - `bundles/bootstrap-yeti`. В строке соединения вбито имя сервера `1-PC` - если подразумевается переноска на другую девелоперскую машину, то лучше использовать `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`. Ну и для создания базы стоит использовать  Code First - иначе ее придется вручную переносить.

Comment: по Code First - посмотрите https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#initialize-db-with-test-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже на то, что вам вместе с проектом надо выкладывать deploy/run скрипты, которые будут заниматься подготовкой окружения для дальнейшей разработки приложения. То есть скрипты, которые создадут нужные каталоги, инициализируют БД и так далее. Да, если проект нуждается в DBE, то в README.md нужно указать что такой-то DBE нужен и что приложение ожидает такую-то пустую базу в этом DBE

Под Linux часто окружение разворачивается в контейнерах. Под Windows, думаю, придётся нативно.

Comment: Я открываю проект в вижле на другой машине, главная страничку загружается, но как только нажимаю другие кнокпи все валиться, выше скрины

Comment: Версии библиотек одинаковые?

Comment: да, наверное!!!